# How to create and return dictionary from for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to read a file and for each line in the file, run an if statement. Then I want all of those statements to be part of a dictionary that I can then return. If I use the return command then it only returns the first line.

```
def orders
    with open('../TestData/test.txt', 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        order_dict = {}
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip()
            if line.find("I", 1, 2) != -1:
               order_id = line[2:10]
               order_dollars = line[10:15]
               order_dict = {"order_info": {"order_id": order_id}, {"order_dollars": order_dollars}

        return order_dict
```

The return only return one line no matter where I place it. I want to use this method in another one, but I want all of the entries, not just the first line.

Expected output is either a list or list of dictionaries that I can search through to modify order_dollars. I need to run another for loop to see if the dollars change and then modify the dollars in saved list or dictionary.

So either

```
{'order_info': {'order_id': '123456789', 'order_dollars': 222} {'order_info': {'order_id': '123456799', 'order_dollars': 111}
```

Or some way for me to modify the order_dollars by running another for loop iterating through the list of dictionaries or a list.

Comment: did you try and run the current code?

Comment: You are redefining `order_dict` inside the loop, so you will only ever get the last thing you looped over. It's not really clear what you are hoping `order_dict` actually looks like, i.e. what are the keys to the dictionary?

Comment: `order_dict = {"order_info": {"order_id": order_id}}` creates a new dictionary every time it's executed. What do you want the final result to be?  A list of dicts? A flat dict with the order_id as the key? In general if you want to modify a dict, you need to not assign `order_dict =` inside the loop, but set a key inside of it (`order_dict[some_key] = some_value`), but that key has to be different for each line...

Comment: I want the script to return a dictionary of key value pairs. For example, all of the order ID's into a flat dictionary that I can then use to manipulate in another method. I need to be able to modify a large set of order IDs.

Comment: What is the expected output ? Please share it. I don't get what would be keys and values, if you have only ID to get, that could be a list

Comment: I have some other variables of course but if we are only using order ID, I want a long list or dictionary of order IDs.


`code`

{'order_info': {'order_id': '123456789',}
{'order_info': {'order_id': '123456799',}


`code`

Comment: But dicts must have unique keys... You can only have ***one*** key `'order_id'`. Why are you even creating a dict? Why not a simple of ids? And then for every line `order_list.append(order_id}`

Comment: I was hoping to be able to search by a certain value to modify other values in the dictionary. Like order_dollars go up and down for a specific order.

Comment: @HoldTheDoor you *really need to be explicit about exactly the output you expect*. Edit the question itself to include this, don't just put it in the comments

Comment: Why not a dict of the form `{order_id: order_dollars}`? And then you just need to change in the loop to `order_dict[order_id] = order_dollars`

Comment: I need to match another dictionary against this one by order id to remove the dollars.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the order_dict as a dict with an array.

```
order_dict = {'order_info' : []}
```

After that, inside the loop you must append the order objects in the array of order_info.

```
order_dict["order_info"].append({"order_id": order_id, "order_dollars": order_dollars})
```

And after all, return the order_dict.

```
return order_dict
```

Comment: Nevermind, this only returns one line still.